# GNOME extensions get re-enabled after logging in

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Whenever I log into my computer (after reboot *or* sleep, doesn't seem to matter), several GNOME extensions get re-enabled.

I've tried uninstalling and the ones I can, but that doesn't seem to do anything.  I've tried uninstalling via the GNOME Shell Integration plugin for Chrome as well as the GNOME Tweak Tool. Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

The extensions in question are "Places Status Indicator," "Workspace Indicator," "AlternateTab," and "Window List."

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNcst.jpg) of extension list before and after logging out and back in:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: Are you ok with uninstalling all extensions?

Comment: I went into tweak tool to try refreshing again, and it gave me the option to remove one of the default extensions. After that, I got the "Ubuntu has experienced an internal error" message, and I had about 5 menu buttons on my panel. After rebooting, only "Places Status Indicator" persists after logging back in.